# how to get data in service file to component in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

How do I fetch data from response and provide it to the component?
The following are the related files.

**api.service file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from'@angular/common/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root'})
export class apiService {  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
     console.log(data)
   });
  }
  public getJSON(): Observable<any> { 
    return this.http.get("../assets/json/json.txt")
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from'@angular/common/http'; 
import { apiService } from  './api.service';
@Component({  
selector: 'app-root', 
templateUrl:'./app.component.html',  
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']})

export class AppComponent {  
title: any;  constructor(private apiService: apiService) { } ngOnInit(data) {
    this.apiService.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
      this.title = data.menu_data.copyright;
      });  }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
     import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient} from  '@angular/common/http';
import { apiService } from  './api.service';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { WorkComponent } from './work/work.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/portfolio.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { BlogComponent } from './blog/blog.component';import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './index/index.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

const routes: Routes = [ 
//{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}, 
 { path: '',component: IndexComponent } 
 { path: 'index',component: IndexComponent },  
  { path: 'about',component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'work',component: WorkComponent } 
{ path: 'portfolio',component: PortfolioComponent },
  { path: 'contact',component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'blog',component: BlogComponent }, 
//{ path: '',   redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}, 
{ path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }];
@NgModule(
{ declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AboutComponent,
        WorkComponent,
        PortfolioComponent,
        ContactComponent,
        BlogComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ErrorComponent,
        IndexComponent
         ],
 imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
        ],
providers: [apiService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get the following error.

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText:
>   "OK", url: "http://localhost:4200/assets/json/json.txt", ok: false, …}

Comment: thats not an error

Comment: when i run application this arror showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the responseType to text since the default one is json in  get method

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from'@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root'})
export class apiService { 
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
     });}
  public getJSON(): Observable<any> { return 
     this.http.get("../assets/json/json.txt",{
      observe:'response',
       responseType:'text'
  })
    }
```

}

Comment: ERROR in src/app/api.service.ts(11,6): error TS7027: Unreachable code detected.
src/app/api.service.ts(12,15): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'response'. Did you mean 'Response'?
src/app/api.service.ts(13,21): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'text'. Did you mean 'Text'?